# WARNING ZEO.zrpc ... ECONNREFUSED Error when starting Plone

Tags: plone

I am setting up a test server for plone in a user directory.

What I did was I copied the entire plone directory in production mode to a user directory and changed the configuration to another port and changed all paths from `/var/plone` to `/home/user/plone` and I also changed all original ports to a different port number like port 8080 and 8081, to 7070 and 7071 for example.

I also changed the permissions of the plone directory to the user where I placed it and to use the account of that user to run buildout. I successfully ran the buildout (`./bin/buildout`) and successfully started zeo (`./bin/zeo start`; output `daemon process started, pid=13123`).

Now the problem is when i'm trying to run the instance (./bin/instance fg), i got this error:

```
 2012-11-09 18:48:45 WARNING ZEO.zrpc (13136) CW: error connecting to ('127.0.0.1', 7100): ECONNREFUSED
 2012-11-09 18:48:50 WARNING ZEO.zrpc (13136) CW: error connecting to ('127.0.0.1', 7100): ECONNREFUSED
 2012-11-09 18:49:00 WARNING ZEO.zrpc (13136) CW: error connecting to ('127.0.0.1', 7100): ECONNREFUSED
 2012-11-09 18:49:20 WARNING ZEO.zrpc (13136) CW: error connecting to ('127.0.0.1', 7100): ECONNREFUSED
```

Can anyone give me an idea how to fix this? thanks a lot.

Comment: Please check for the ZEO log and check that it is actually starting; the `daemon process started` message does not tell you anything about wether or not it was successful in binding to the port, for example.

Comment: hi, i tried starting zeo again while tailing zeo.log and i got this live error: 2012-11-12T08:30:40 sleep 1 to avoid rapid restarts
2012-11-12T08:30:40 pid 21332: exit status 1
2012-11-12T08:30:41 spawned process pid=21333
2012-11-12T08:30:44 sleep 2 to avoid rapid restarts
...

Comment: So your ZEO process is not starting, probably because it cannot bind to the port. Try running it in foreground mode to confirm.

Answer (score 5):

If after checking the ports and such as Mikko and Martijn have suggested you are still seeing this, try waiting a bit. I often see this message during client startup when the ZEO instance has not finished building the Data.fs.index file. It can take a good long while if the database is large or the machine is under-powered.

Answer (score 1):

I used following steps to solve this:
First i stop and restart server by using:

```
bin/plonectl server stop/start
```

i created two clients for my site so i started them one by one by using following commands:

```
bin/plonectl client1 start
bin/plonectl client2 start or fg
```

and finally i got my solution.I hope it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot connect the ZEO server.

Check that ZEO server is running by manually forming a TCP/IP connection to the target port:

```
   telnet 127.0.0.1 7100
```

If it doesn't respond

- The port is wrong

or

- ZEO server is not running

Comment: hi, i got this error: Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: It means ZEO server is not running in that port.

Comment: You can also try this command bin/zeoserver fg to start zeoserver on foreground and see possible start up errors. On succesful start up it reports nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error because of permissions/ownership problems on the var/filestorage directory that prevent zeoserver from writing a database lock file, even when you can run the buildout without errors. Notice of the problem will appear as a traceback on the zeoserver process stdout (nothing on stderr):

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/srv/foo/var/filestorage/Data.fs.lock'
```

Adjust permissions and ownership as necessary on var/filestorage to ensure the user that runs your zeoserver has rwx on the directory.